# Duplicate Slashes in Retrofit URL

Tags: android, url, path, retrofit

I'm running into a problem with duplicate slashes and I'm wondering if there is a solution built into Retrofit.

My server provides the base URL we should be using which will look something like this: `.setEndpoint(http://some.url.com/)`

The server also passes down a path URI that should be appended to that endpoint (with various requests). So my server might send back `/channels/videos`.

This gets handed to Retrofit through the following method

```
@GET("/{uri}")
void GET(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader, @Path(value = "uri", encode = false) String uri,
         @Header("Cache-Control") String cacheHeaderValue, Callback<Object> callback);
```

This is then problematic because the URL that is getting hit with the GET method is `http://some.url.com//channels/videos` which will not work correctly in my situation.

I tried manually stripping out the trailing slash from my base endpoint - but I still saw a duplicate slash which I'm assuming resulted from the `"/{uri}"` and the `/channels/videos`.

I think my problem would be fixed by removing the leading slash in `"/{uri}"` but that isn't allowed in Retrofit. And removing the leading slash in the path URI I get back from my server isn't entirely feasible.

`throw methodError("URL path \"%s\" must start with '/'.", path);`

`retrofit.RetrofitError: GET: URL path "{uri}" must start with '/'.`

***Is there another solution to this problem?***

Relevant Links:

[Possible duplicate but they describe it a little differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018190/retrofit-and-slash-characters-in-path)

[Jake Wharton saying it should be de-duped in what I think is the situation I'm describing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304174/why-is-retrofit-adding-a-trailing-slash-to-all-urls#comment43071925_27304517)

[Maybe what Jake Wharton was referencing](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RequestBuilder.java#L353)

[Currently unanswered issue asking Jake this same question](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/420)

Comment: Why don't you remove the / in your end point URL? To something like this
`http://some.url.com`

Comment: `I tried manually stripping out the trailing slash from my base endpoint...`

I also thought that would fix it, but it appears to be coming from the leading slash in both the annotation as well as the path I get from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Retrofit 2.0.0-beta3. It requires changing the method signature/annotations in your service class. The signature for the original GET method is now:

```
@GET
Call<Object> GET(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader, @Url String uri,
                 @QueryMap Map<String, String> options, @Header("Cache-Control") String cacheHeaderValue);
```

This is using `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'`

If you're still on the previous version of Retrofit, I solved the problem temporarily with the following helper (calling it on the uri passed to GET):

```
public static String validateUri(String uri) {
  if (uri.charAt(0) == '/') {
      uri = uri.substring(1);
  }
  return uri;
}
```